# res_query not following res_init, unsets what was set

Tags: dns, debian, glibc, resolve

Please consider this code, where I am calling `res_init()`, and setting 192.168.1.77 as the sole nameserver. However when `res_query` runs, apparantly it is re-doing the res_init, and going back to the first 3   nameservers from resolv.conf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    u_char nsbuf[4096];
    char dispbuf[4096];
    ns_msg msg;
    ns_rr rr;
    int i, j, l;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: %s <domain>[...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit (1);
    }
    res_init();
    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < _res.nscount; i++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr) , str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("Before:  nameserver %d : %s\n", i,str);
    }

    // set to use 192.168.1.77 as nameserver
     _res.nscount = 1;
     _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_family = AF_INET;
     _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.77");
     _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_port = htons(53);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < _res.nscount; i++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr) , str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("After:  nameserver %d : %s\n", i,str);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("ns count before res_query %d\n", _res.nscount);
       l = res_query (argv[i], ns_c_any, ns_t_a, nsbuf, sizeof (nsbuf));
    printf("ns count after res_query %d\n", _res.nscount);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < _res.nscount; i++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr) , str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("After res_query:  nameserver %d : %s\n", i,str);
    }

        if (l < 0) {
            perror (argv[i]);
        } else {
            ns_initparse (nsbuf, l, &msg);
            printf ("---------------------\n%s :\n", argv[i]);
            l = ns_msg_count (msg, ns_s_an);
            for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                ns_parserr (&msg, ns_s_an, j, &rr);
                ns_sprintrr (&msg, &rr, NULL, NULL, dispbuf, sizeof (dispbuf));
                printf ("%s\n", dispbuf);
            }
        }
    }

    exit (0);
}
```

Below is the output where we can see this happening:

```
$ ./a.out cnn.com
Before:  nameserver 0 : 127.0.0.1
Before:  nameserver 1 : 192.168.1.1
Before:  nameserver 2 : 1.1.1.1
After:  nameserver 0 : 192.168.1.77
ns count before res_query 1
ns count after res_query 3
After res_query:  nameserver 0 : 127.0.0.1     /// <----- these... 
After res_query:  nameserver 1 : 192.168.1.1   /// <----- these... 
After res_query:  nameserver 2 : 1.1.1.1       /// <----- these... 
---------------------
cnn.com :
cnn.com.        58S IN A    151.101.129.67
cnn.com.        58S IN A    151.101.1.67
cnn.com.        58S IN A    151.101.65.67
cnn.com.        58S IN A    151.101.193.67
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I do `res_query` without it doing another `res_init()` behind my back?

**Update 1**

Thank you for the detailed and thorough reply. Below, I am able to retain the nameservers I add, after I've modified to call `res_init`, and then `res_mkquery()`.

However, it still more of a miss:

```
 $ time ./warm cnn.com 8.8.8.8
PACKETSZ: 512
Before:  nameserver 0 : 127.0.0.1
Before:  nameserver 1 : 192.168.1.1
Before:  nameserver 2 : 1.1.1.1
queryLen is 25
setting 8.8.8.8 as nameserver
After:  nameserver 0 : 8.8.8.8
ns count before res_query 1
res_query failed!
ns count after res_query 1
After res_query:  nameserver 0 : 8.8.8.8
cnn.com: Connection timed out
ns count before res_query 1
res_query failed!
ns count after res_query 1
After res_query:  nameserver 0 : 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8: Connection timed out

real    0m0.131s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Although I see traffic going to 8.8.8.8.

**warm.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    u_char nsbuf[4096];
    u_char warm_buf[4096];
    char dispbuf[4096];

    //char nameserver[] = "127.0.0.1";
    //char nameserver[] = "192.168.1.166";
    char *nameserver = argv[2];
    ns_msg msg;
    ns_rr rr;
    int i, j, l;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: %s <domain>[...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit (1);
    }


    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

     //res_init();

    printf("PACKETSZ: %d\n",PACKETSZ);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < _res.nscount; i++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr) , str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("Before:  nameserver %d : %s\n", i,str);
    }
     int queryLen = res_mkquery(
                     ns_o_query,      /* regular query         */
                     argv[1],          /* the domain to look up */
                     ns_c_any,         /* Internet type         */
                     ns_t_a,        /* Look up an A record */
                     (u_char *)NULL,  /* always NULL       */
                     0,               /* length of NULL        */
                     (u_char *)NULL,  /* always NULL       */
                     warm_buf,/* buffer for the query  */
                     sizeof(warm_buf));  /* size of the buffer    */


    printf("queryLen is %d\n" , queryLen);
    //printf("queryLen is %d\n" , strlen(warm_buf) );

    // set to use 192.168.1.77 as nameserver
    printf("setting %s as nameserver\n", nameserver);
     _res.nscount = 1;
     _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_family = AF_INET;
     _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(nameserver);
     _res.nsaddr_list[0].sin_port = htons(53);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < _res.nscount; i++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr) , str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("After:  nameserver %d : %s\n", i,str);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("ns count before res_query %d\n", _res.nscount);
       l = res_query (argv[i], ns_c_any, ns_t_a, nsbuf, sizeof (nsbuf));
    printf(" -------------------------- >>> l is %d\n", l);
    printf("ns count after res_query %d\n", _res.nscount);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < _res.nscount; i++){
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr) , str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("After res_query:  nameserver %d : %s\n", i,str);
    }

        if (l < 0) {
            perror (argv[i]);
        } else {
            ns_initparse (nsbuf, l, &msg);
            printf ("---------------------\n%s :\n", argv[i]);
            l = ns_msg_count (msg, ns_s_an);
            for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                ns_parserr (&msg, ns_s_an, j, &rr);
                ns_sprintrr (&msg, &rr, NULL, NULL, dispbuf, sizeof (dispbuf));
                printf ("%s\n", dispbuf);
            }
        }
    }

    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: raspbian, so yes, Debian. 

`$ ldd bugme 
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ef2b000)
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76ed2000)
 libresolv.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2 (0x76ead000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76d6e000)
 /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76ee8000)`. 

glibc version, `gnu_get_libc_version()` says `2.24`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Debian 9 (stretch) and earlier versions use a [custom, downstream-only patch to automatically reload `/etc/resolv.conf` if it has changed](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/blob/stretch/debian/patches/any/local-dynamic-resolvconf.diff).  The way this patch is written, the cache is only updated when the internal `__res_maybe_init` function is called, which `res_init` does not do.  This means that a call to the actual resolver functions (such as `res_query`) results in a cold cache in `__res_maybe_init`, a reload occurs, and your changes to `_res` are thrown away.

Upstream implemented [automatic `/etc/resolv.conf` reloading glibc 2.26](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=984).  The upstream approach is very different and attempts to handle `_res` patching by applications:

- There is a unified cache, and calling `res_init` updates it.
- If a reload of `/etc/resolv.conf` is necessary, glibc checks if the `_res` values still reflect what was *previously* loaded from `/etc/resolv.conf`, and if the values a different, the new `/etc/resolv.conf` contents is *not* applied and the current `_res` settings are not overwritten.
- There is a new `RES_NORELOAD`/`noreload` resolver option which disables automated reloading completely.

These changes will be part of the upcoming Debian version 10 (buster).

If you do not want to upgrade glibc, you can make it much less likely that the Debian-specific reloading code overrides your changes if you trigger a call to `__res_maybe_init` before patching `_res`, instead of calling `res_init`.  One way to do this without sending a query is to call `res_mkquery` with some dummy arguments.  This will pre-warm the cache, and a reload will only occur if the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is changed on disk (at which point your changes will still be overwritten—I do not think there is a way to prevent this with the old Debian versions).